# Wrong width for image

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox, lightbox2

I use this code with lightbox 2.6:

```
<a href="/media/photologue/photos/img_big.jpg" data-lightbox="img-1" title=""><img src="/media/photologue/photos/img_small.jpg"></a>
```

`img_big` size is 7500x6105 and `img_small` size is 150x150. But when I click on the link lightbox shows image that is too narrow, it's size is 298x488.
Anyone knows why this could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/69#issuecomment-21787143.
I just needed to add following css:

```
.lb-image{
    max-width: inherit;
}
```